Take a screenshot of specific element with uiautomator2, without cropping the entire screen
Here is my code. Basically, I am screenshotting the entire screen and then using Pillow to crop.
import uiautomator2, time
from PIL import Image

    def screenshot(e,f):
        d.screenshot("full.png")
        img = Image.open("full.png")
        l = d(resourceIdMatches=e).info["bounds"]
        cropped = img.crop((l['left'], l['top'], l['right'], l['bottom'])).save(f, format='JPEG')
    
    screenshot("com.lbe.parallel.intl:id/iv_i.*","test.jpg")

The problem is that it takes 1.75 seconds, which is unfeasibly slow for my purposes.
